# How to avoid KotlinNullPointerException when creating a new User object?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-null-safety

I have this authentication code in Firebase:

```
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val firebaseUser = auth.currentUser!!
        val user = User(firebaseUser.uid, firebaseUser.displayName!!) //KotlinNullPointerException
    } 
}
```

This my User class:

```
data class User constructor(var uid: String? = null): Serializable {
    var name: String? = null

    constructor(uid: String, name: String) : this(uid) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

And I'm getting a `KotlinNullPointerException` at the highlighted line. How can the call of the constructor produce this exception? How can I avoid it?

Comment: I think since the `name` is optional variable just put it right into the primary constructor like you did with uid, and donot use the `!!` operator. Like `User(var uid: String? = null, var name: String? = null)`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Thanks but I need it this way.

Comment: `this way` which way?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu I need a constructor with one argument as well as one with two arguments.

Comment: A constructor with optional parameter generates overload constructor at the time of compilation, its just the same. You can call it like `User("my-id")` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare your class like:

```kotlin
data class User(var uid: String? = null, var name: String? = null) : Serializable
```

And then you can call it like:

```kotlin
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        auth.currentUser?.apply {  // safe call operator, calls given block when currentUser is not null
            val user = User(uid, displayName)
        }
    } 
}
```

It is possible to create instance of User like this:

```kotlin
User() // defaults to null as specified
User("id") // only id is set, name is null
User(name = "test-name") // only name is set id is null
```

The `= null` exactly allows the invokation to pass the parameter optionally, when not passed defaulting to `null`.

**Edit:** As suggested by @GastónSaillén, you should use Parcelable in Android.

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class User(var uid: String? = null, var name: String? = null) : Parcelable
```

Comment: You mean `val user = User(auth.currentUser.uid, auth.currentUser.displayName)`?

Comment: @LisDya `apply` block passes auth.currentUser as `this` variable inside the lambda so `uid` implicitly calls `this.uid` that implicitly calls on `auth.currentUser`

Comment: I would use Parcelable instead of Serializable since is better for Android than the Serializable interface

Comment: I did exactly what you said but when calling `val user = User(uid =  "test-uid", name = "test-name")` I get still get `KotlinNullPointerException`. Should do anything else?

Comment: @LisDya I really don't get how you get it, does the stacktrace point exactly to this line? There must be a non-null safe call `!!` from where KotlinNullPointerException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle nullable fields in Kotlin like this:

```
val user = auth.currentUser?.let { firebaseUser -> 
   firebaseUser.displayName?.let { displayName -> 
      User(firebaseUser.uid,  displayName)
   }
}
```

Operator `!!` is very dangerous and should be avoided in most cases

Comment: And if I have another argument `firebaseUser.email`, how can I solve this?

Comment: In this case you can add one more inner `let {}` function call on `firebaseUser`. It will looks like same as `displayName` handling